# local ga.js prevents app from syncing on Samsung SmartTV 2013

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, samsung-smart-tv, smart-tv

I'm trying to test my app on a new Samsung SmartTV 2013, however when I include google's ga.js locally into my bundle the TV rejects the app and will not install it at all.

The error message provided points to this page: http://www.samsungdforum.com/support/tvappssecurity. Which is pretty vague and unhelpful in this situation.

Any one have a work around for this? I've already looked on the Samsung D Forum.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The TVAppsSecurity is well known error - I have seen it tens of times. It basically says that your code violates Samsung security restrictions. In practice the static source code analysis on TV detects some security flaws.

Note that it is up to you to identify the issue and fix it. Since you know the file that causes the problem - you can easily separate it into test project. Then just start deleting portions of the code until you will be able to install the application. It is annoying, but it will take 60 minutes maximum. Note that sometimes it is even enough to rename the file.

I am not sure if the ga.js hosting is really a problem (see there https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1032389?hl=en)

Answer (score 0):

You can include `ga.js` by loading it from external host. In this case it will not be checked during install on TV.